# Functional test coverage report with node-jscoverage , mocha and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, code-coverage, mocha.js

I want to get the coverage of a functional test on an express endpoint.
I have made this simple setup.

nodetest/index.js

```
module.exports = process.env.APP_COV
  ? require('./lib-cov')
  : require('./lib');
```

nodetest/lib/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/hello.txt', function(req, res){
  res.send('Hello World');
});
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
});
```

nodetest/test/simple.js

```
var request = require('supertest');

describe("Node Test Service",function(){
    it('Should return 200 OK trying to login', function (done) {
        request("http://localhost:3000")
            .get('/hello.txt')
            .expect(200)
            .end(function (err, res) {
            if(err)
                throw err;
            done();
            });
    });
});
```

nodetest/Makefile

```
all: test test-cov
test:
    @./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R xunit > reporter.xml

test-cov: lib-cov
    @APP_COV=1  ./node_modules/.bin/mocha -R html-cov > coverage.html

lib-cov:
    @./node-jscoverage/jscoverage lib lib-cov

node-jscoverage:
    @git clone git://github.com/visionmedia/node-jscoverage.git
    @cd node-jscoverage/ && ./configure && make


.PHONY: test
```

I am running the server with the env variable on and then fire the tests
and it yields an empty coverage.html.
Is it possible to get the coverage i am asking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that in order to work, i had to start the express server right from the tests.
I also needed to add a line on top of my tests

```
var lib = process.env['COV']?'../lib-cov' : '../lib';
//run express
var app = require(lib)
```

so that when you run the coverage test, you include the instrumented files.